# Handling accented letters in QRegularExpressions in Qt5

Tags: c++, regex, validation, qt5, qregularexpression

I am accepting input for the full name of the user using `QLineEdit`, and I want to accept

**all international characters**

such as "é" in French or  "æ", "ø", and "å" in Norwegian, while at the same time using `QRegularExpressionValidator` to ensure the name is in fact a valid name (no non-letter characters).

So the question is, do I have to list all such accented characters exhaustively, or is there some kind of "word class" that can be used, that allows me to trust Qt to provide an updated list for me?

What would be the best approach?

Comment: The canonical list on this topic: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @MSalters: The link seems broken

Comment: TX, and btw I simplified in the post saying "user name". Actually I am generating fictious robot's names so I get to determine the rules for what is a valid name or not :D

Comment: Whaat? And not accepting robot names with non-breaking spaces in them, RTL control characters and whatnot?

Comment: Damn straight skippy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a `\p{L}` Unicode category class that will match all Unicode base letters.

This will match 1 or more letter chunks:

```
QRegularExpression re("\\p{L}+");
```

All uppercase letter variants: `\p{Lu}`

All lowercase letter variants: `\p{Ll}`

See [*Unicode categories*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) for more information.

Comment: Holy macarony that was fast! Kudos to you! I will test it straight away!

Comment: Q: What about lower/upper case subsets?

Comment: Q: What about them? The vast majority of Unicode characters is neither.